# Any way to see changes to Github issue description?

Tags: github

If someone goes into an issue and edits the description, is there any way to see what was changed? Or see what the original description was?

Comment: I know this may be too much work but maybe you could keep a master copy of all issues for reference? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Issues don't seem to have multiple versions.

A good illustration is in the [GitHub API v3 on Issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/): you can get or edit an issue, but you wouldn't be able to query the different versions of an updated issue.

Comment: Thanks VonC, I figured that was the case, but was hoping it wasn't. Guess I'll just have to tell my coworker to stop changing them. It makes it confusing when the code and tests don't match the issue. (I'm not awarding the bounty yet in the hopes that someone knows a magic way to do this, but you'll get it when time runs out)